# Efficiently read the output of several children

Tags: c++, fork, exec

I am writing a program which runs an external command (in this case, `apt-cache show PACKAGE` but it will change when I'll port my program to other distros) several times. A lot of times (like 40000+). I am using the output of the run software to fill some containers.

Currently, google-pprof says that I spend around 30% of my time in the fork call (main() takes 5/3155 samples, and __libc_fork() 1019/1037).
I already reduced the time wasted by trying to reduce main program memory usage before the fork, but I still think I can improve the situation.

The problem is I do not know how. Either I move many container instances as global variables to free more things before the call to exec(), but I do not really like using globals, or "I" find another solution.
The ideal thing would probably be a way to just take the output of a command without doing a real fork, but I have no idea if this is even possible.

I'll add to this that I would prefer something portable between Linux and *BSD systems.

Comment: The only system call that executes a process is exec() (I am referring to all family of exec functions by the exec() reference). exec() always replaces the current process with the new executable. As such, if you still need to continue running the current process, you must fork(). There are no other options.

Comment: To my knowledge fork is copy-on-write in Linux and thus it matters little how much memory you used before calling fork().